# Delete gnome terminal configuration

Tags: terminal, gnome

I made a mistake in my gnome terminal configuration. I entered a command to start with in the preferences, but that command fails, and now all I get is a window that opens and closes right away, and I basically can't use gnome terminal anymore :-( Is there any way I can remove the configuration file and restart fresh??

Thanks!

Comment: I sympathize with you, but I'm afraid this isn't the right place.

Comment: Here, this will help http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1243774.html

Comment: Sorry if it's not the right place :-( I won't do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$HOME/.gconfd/saved_state
```

the above file might be of interest depending on exactly what configuration you changed.  Of course, it holds configuration from other programs as well.

Comment: I wiped out .gconf and .gconfd, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You would probably need to log out and in again to get the new configuration to take, or kill the necessary processes (gconf*)

Answer (score 3):

Open the XTerm (Standard terminal for linux) and enter this command

> gnome-terminal -e bash

It opens the gnome-terminal. Open profile preferences and configure your terminal to "Hold the terminal open".

[Editing preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERMcB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the newer gnome terminal that uses dconf, it's a little trickier, but still doable:

Profiles are stored with a UUID, you need to find the UUID of the profile to remove:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/ | less
```

Search for a `visible-name='...'` entry matching the profile you want to remove.  Look above that for the section header like `[legacy/profiles:/:...]`.  The full name of the item you want to delete is thus `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:...`.  Delete it thus:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:...
```

Side note: This Q&A probably should be moved to unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/853013/238607  : I followed this answer and then on the profiles I selected "Reset Recursively".